# php calculator - Switch statement issues

Tags: php, html, calculator

Here is my form

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Digets">
        <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Digets">
        <select name="operator">
            <option>Add</option>
            <option>Subtract</option>
            <option>Multiply</option>
            <option>Divide</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Check for the answer</button>
        <p>Your answer is : </p>
    </form>

<?php 


        if (isset($_GET['$submit'])){
            $result1 = $_GET['$num1'];
            $result2 = $_GET['$num2'];
            $operator = $_GET['$operator'];


            switch ('$operator'){

                case "Add":
                    echo $result1 + $result2;
                break;
                case "Subtract":
                    echo $result1 - $result2;
                break;
                case "Multiply":
                    echo $result1 * $result2;
                break;
                case "Divide":
                    echo $result1 / $result2;
                break;

            }
        }

    ?>
```

When i click on the calculate button I don't see an answer and i tried fixing all my bugs but it seems to me as if their is something wrong with the switch.

Comment: `switch ($operator){` no quotes your gets are wrong to ..  `$_GET['num2'];` etc

Comment: I took off the quotes but it has the same issue. Also what do you mean my gets are wrong?

Comment: Ok, then echo `$operator` before the switch to see what the value is. OR, add a default case too see if it reaches that point.

Comment: ive just tried doing that too and no answer before the switch either

Comment: your options are missing values `<option value='Divide'>Divide</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

you are making some mistake while getting values and switch parameter.

like you are geetting value `$_GET['$num1']` instead you need to use `$_GET['num1']`

as you just need to pass variable switch ($operator) instead `switch ('$operator')` of quotation mark.

```
  <?php 


            if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
                $result1 = $_GET['num1'];
                $result2 = $_GET['num2'];
                $operator = $_GET['operator'];


                switch ($operator){

                    case 'Add':
                        $FResult =$result1 + $result2;
                        echo "Result:"+ $FResult ;
                        break;
                    case 'Subtract':
                        $FResult =$result1 - $result2;
                        echo "Result:"+ $FResult ;
                        break;
                    case 'Multiply':
                        $FResult =$result1 * $result2;
                        echo "Result:"+ $FResult ;
                        break;
                    case 'Divide':
                        $FResult =$result1 / $result2;
                        echo "Result:"+ $FResult ;
                        break;
                    default :
                         echo "wrong";

                }
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: you should explain your changes, not just dump code

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
 <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder="Digets">
 <input type="number" name="num2" placeholder="Digets">
 <select name="operator">
  <option value="+">Add</option>
  <option value="-">Subtract</option>
  <option value="*">Multiply</option>
  <option value="/">Divide</option>
 </select>
 <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Check for the answer</button>
 <p>Your answer is : </p>
</form>
<?php 

        if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
            $result1 = $_REQUEST['num1'];
            $result2 = $_REQUEST['num2'];
            $operator = $_REQUEST['operator'];
            
            $res = $result1.$operator.$result2;            
            $p = eval('return '.$res.';');
   print $p;
       }      

?>
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder="Digets">
 <input type="number" name="num2" placeholder="Digets">
 <select name="operator">
  <option>Add</option>
  <option>Subtract</option>
  <option>Multiply</option>
  <option>Divide</option>
 </select>
 <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Check for the answer</button>
 <p>Your answer is : </p>
</form>
<?php 

        if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
            $result1 = $_REQUEST['num1'];
            $result2 = $_REQUEST['num2'];
            $operator = $_REQUEST['operator'];
            switch ($operator){

                case "Add":
                    echo $result1 + $result2;
                break;
                case "Subtract":
                    echo $result1 - $result2;
                break;
                case "Multiply":
                    echo $result1 * $result2;
                break;
                case "Divide":
                    echo $result1 / $result2;
                break;

            }
        }

?>


Another way:

<form>
 <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder="Digets">
 <input type="number" name="num2" placeholder="Digets">
 <select name="operator">
  <option value="+">Add</option>
  <option value="-">Subtract</option>
  <option value="*">Multiply</option>
  <option value="/">Divide</option>
 </select>
 <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Check for the answer</button>
 <p>Your answer is : </p>
</form>
<?php 

        if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
            $result1 = $_REQUEST['num1'];
            $result2 = $_REQUEST['num2'];
            $operator = $_REQUEST['operator'];
            
            $res = $result1.$operator.$result2;            
            $p = eval('return '.$res.';');
   print $p;
       }      

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you have made:

1). You are passing variable directly into get element i.e, it should be like $_GET['submit'] instead of $_GET['$submit'];

2). You are passing string instead of variable i.e, switch ('$operator') should be switch ($operator)

check it out where you have made mistake

```
<form method="GET" action="">
        <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Digets">
        <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Digets">
        <select name="operator">
            <option>Add</option>
            <option>Subtract</option>
            <option>Multiply</option>
            <option>Divide</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Check for the answer</button>
        <p>Your answer is : </p>
    </form>


<?php


        if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
            $result1 = $_GET['num1'];
            $result2 = $_GET['num2'];
            $operator = $_GET['operator'];


            switch ($operator){

                case "Add":
                    echo $result1 + $result2;
                break;
                case "Subtract":
                    echo $result1 - $result2;
                break;
                case "Multiply":
                    echo $result1 * $result2;
                break;
                case "Divide":
                    echo $result1 / $result2;
                break;

            }
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for PHP solution, here is one:-

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $result1 = $_POST['num1'];
        $result2 = $_POST['num2'];
        $operator = $_POST['operator'];


        switch($operator){

            case "Add":
                $res = +$result1 + +$result2;
            break;
            case "Subtract":
                $res = +$result1 - +$result2;
            break;
            case "Multiply":
                $res = +$result1 * +$result2;
            break;
            case "Divide":
                $res = +$result1 / +$result2;
            break;

        }
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" placeholder="Digets">
    <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" placeholder="Digets">
    <select name="operator" id="operator">
        <option value="Add">Add</option>
        <option value="Subtract">Subtract</option>
        <option value="Multiply">Multiply</option>
        <option value="Divide">Divide</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate" />
    <p>Your answer is : <input name="res" value="<?php echo $res; ?>"></p>
</form>
```

This is what you were looking for .

Comment: Please check the above code , its in PHP only and running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should set option value in select tag (operator which you want for calculator) `<option value="">`.

change you input `type="text"` into `type="number"`

```
<form method="GET">
        <input type="number" name="num1">
        <input type="number" name="num2">
        <select name="operator">
            <option value='+'>Add</option>
            <option value='-'>Subtract</option>
            <option value='*'>Multiply</option>
            <option value='/'>Divide</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">calculate</button>
        <p>Answer :</p>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
        $num1 = $_GET['num1'];
        $num2 = $_GET['num2'];
        $operator = $_GET['operator'];


            switch ($operator){

                case "+":
                    echo $num1 + $num2;
                break;
                case "-":
                    echo $num1 - $num2;
                break;
                case "*":
                    echo $num1 * $num2;
                break;
                case "/":
                    echo $num1 / $num2;
                break;

            }
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

what you have done is that you are calculating it in the back-end and the form is refreshing the page , but not displaying the result anywhere on the page . Its better to do with a JQuery so that result will come instantly without page refresh . Just check the code below:-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on('click', function(){
        var num1 = $("#num1").val() ;
        var num2 = $("#num2").val() ;
        var operator = $("#operator").val() ;
        var result = 0 ;

        switch(operator){
            case "Add":
               result = +num1 + +num2 ;
               document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result ;
               break ;
            case "Subtract":
               result = +num1 - +num2 ;
               document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result ;
               break ;
            case "Multiply":
               result = +num1 * +num2 ;
               document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result ;
               break ;
            case "Divide":
               result = +num1 / +num2 ;
               document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result ;
               break ;
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" placeholder="Digets">
    <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" placeholder="Digets">
    <select name="operator" id="operator">
        <option value="Add">Add</option>
        <option value="Subtract">Subtract</option>
        <option value="Multiply">Multiply</option>
        <option value="Divide">Divide</option>
    </select>
    <button name="submit" id="submit">Check for the answer</button>
    <p>Your answer is : <span id="res"></span></p>
</div>
```

This is running successfully .

Comment: Smith , are you really unaware about the power of JQuery ? Its a calculator , the result should not come after page refresh . Just run the code and check how fast and how accurate it is .

Comment: Answering the question in jQuery doesn't help him figure out why his PHP doesn't work.